# How to get the data from api on bases of start date and end date in ReactNative?

Tags: api, react-native, redux

how do I get a list of data from API according to start date and end date in react-native?

```
componentDidMount = async() => {

    var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken')
    var response =  await this.props.listData({'startDate':,'endDate':},accessToken)

    if(!response.error){
       this.setState({})
    }
}
```

Comment: Your API needs to support it and what is the structure it is accepting. And you need to pass the start and end date something like `{startDate: '01/05/2019', endDate: '02/05/2019'}`.Elaborate more on what you need.

Comment: There is one API of listing data, in that I have to send request param start date and end date. From that, I will get a response in the form of a list, which was in between those two dates. And actually the first time I calling API so I don't have much idea on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount = async() => {   
start = 0;  
    var today = new Date();  
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);  
    var day = today.getDay() - start;  
    var date = today.getDate() - day;  
    var Start = new Date(today.setDate(date));  
    var End= new Date(today.setDate(date + 6));  
    var StartDate = new Date(Start);  
    var EndDate = new Date(End);  
    var startingDate = StartDate.getDate()+"-"+(new Date(Start).getMonth()+1)+"- 
    "+ new Date(Start).getFullYear();  
    var endingDate = EndDate.getDate()+"-"+(new Date(End).getMonth()+1)+"-"+ new 
    Date(End).getFullYear();  
    var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('accesToken')        
    var response await = this.props.posthistory({'startDate':startingDate,'endDate':endingDate,'page':'1'},accesstoken) 
      if(!response.error){  
        this.setState({response})  
    }
}
```